# binary file of the helloworld.go generated by Grumpy does not get generated

Tags: python, go, grumpy

I wrote a `HelloWorld.py` and using `grumpy` I compiled the `HelloWorld.py` to a Go source code. but after running `go build`, the binary file does not get generated, the `go build` command was executed successfully without any error but there was no binary file found in the folder.

here is the code inside HelloWorld.py:

```
def hello():
        print("hello, world")
```

here is the generated code in hello.go:

```
package __main__

import πg "grumpy/build/src/grumpy"

var Code *πg.Code

func init() {
    Code = πg.NewCode("<module>", "hello.py", nil, 0, func(πF *πg.Frame, _ []*πg.Object) (*πg.Object, *πg.BaseException) {
        var πR *πg.Object; _ = πR
        var πE *πg.BaseException; _ = πE
        ßhello := πg.InternStr("hello")
        var πTemp001 *πg.Object
        _ = πTemp001
        var πTemp002 []πg.Param
        _ = πTemp002
        for ; πF.State() >= 0; πF.PopCheckpoint() {
            switch πF.State() {
            case 0:
            default: panic("unexpected function state")
            }
            // line 1: def hello(): print "hello, world"
            πF.SetLineno(1)
            πTemp002 = make([]πg.Param, 0)
            πTemp001 = πg.NewFunction(πg.NewCode("hello", "hello.py", πTemp002, 0, func(πF *πg.Frame, πArgs []*πg.Object) (*πg.Object, *πg.BaseException) {
                var πTemp001 []*πg.Object
                _ = πTemp001
                var πR *πg.Object; _ = πR
                var πE *πg.BaseException; _ = πE
                for ; πF.State() >= 0; πF.PopCheckpoint() {
                    switch πF.State() {
                    case 0:
                    default: panic("unexpected function state")
                    }
                    // line 1: def hello(): print "hello, world"
                    πF.SetLineno(1)
                    πTemp001 = make([]*πg.Object, 1)
                    πTemp001[0] = πg.NewStr("hello, world").ToObject()
                    if πE = πg.Print(πF, πTemp001, true); πE != nil {
                        continue
                    }
                }
                if πE != nil {
                    πR = nil
                } else if πR == nil {
                    πR = πg.None
                }
                return πR, πE
            }), πF.Globals()).ToObject()
            if πE = πF.Globals().SetItem(πF, ßhello.ToObject(), πTemp001); πE != nil {
                continue
            }
        }
        return nil, πE
    })
    πg.RegisterModule("__main__", Code)
}
```

when i try to add the main function to the end of the hello.go and call init() like this :

```
func main() {
    init()
}
```

i get this error when i run `go build`

```
can't load package: package .:  main.go:1:2: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
```

Comment: Where is your `main` function?

Comment: Go can only build a binary from a `main` package with a `main` function.

Comment: I do not have a main function I tried to edit the generated code to have a main function but it fails to compile , how can I call the hello world function in a main function ? The code looks very unfamiliar.

Comment: i added the main function to the end of the script to call the init() but i get this error :    `can't load package: package .: `
                    `main.go:1:2: expected 'package', found 'EOF'`

Comment: @sam_com: you don't call `init()`, it's called automatically during package initialization.

Comment: I see, then how should I implement the main function, so I can generate an executable binary file using go build ? also is `grumpy/build/src/grumpy` a correct path?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but following code in python file may work:

```
def hello():
        print("hello, world")
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    hello()
```

Now go will create its own main function and is likely to work. (disclaimer: I have not yet tried this myself).